# How to encrypt in a pgcrypto compatible way in python

Tags: python, postgresql, public-key-encryption, gnupg, pgcrypto

For a project I am working on I would like to use a pgcrypto compatible encryption in python. And specific the public key encryption part.

The problem I have is that most (all) of the implementations make use of subprocess like approaches to fork gpg, as I have to encrypt a lot of data (50.000+ entries per session) this approach will not work for me.

Can someone give me some pointers how that this could be achieved?

Comment: Depends what type of encryption you use. First, are you using raw encryption funtions like "encrypt(data bytea, key bytea, type text) returns bytea" or PGP stuff like "pgp_pub_encrypt(data text, key bytea [, options text ]) returns bytea"?

Comment: Both options are open and I have no strong favour for one or the other

Comment: Ok I thought you hade already chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at PyCrypto, it doesn't seem to use forking. pgcrypto can be configured to fit most crypto configurations.

Comment: Thank you, I guess that my question was nog clear enough. I am looking for a more detailed answer from someone that has experience with a simular problem. I know PyCrypto could be used, but I have no clear idea on how to use it correctly.